# Multiple static folders & templates folders in flask app

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, project-structure

Is it possible to have more than one static folder in flask app? I have some .css and .js files which I am using only for certain blueprint and would like to have the files in same directory as blueprint.

My app has structure like this:

```
app
|
| blueprints
| |
| | blueprint_1
| | |
| | | views.py
| | | __init__.py
| | 
| | blueprint_2
| | |
| | | views.py
| | | __init__.py
| 
| static
| |
| | css, js, etc.
```

And I would like to have structure like this:

```
app
|
| blueprints
| |
| | blueprint_1
| | |
| | | views.py
| | | __init__.py
| | | static
| | | |
| | | | certain css, js, etc
| | 
| | blueprint_2
| | |
| | | views.py
| | | __init__.py
| | | static
| | | |
| | | | certain css, js, etc
| 
| static
| |
| | css, js, etc.
```

And similar thing with templates. 
While I am using .js file in template I access it with:

`{{url_for('static'), filename='jsfile'}}`

Comment: A sample app using multiple assets folders: https://hackersandslackers.com/flask-blueprints/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

According to [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/#static-files), if the blueprint does not have a url_prefix, it is not possible to access the blueprint’s static folder.

The solution then is:

Add url_prefix to Blueprint:

`some_blueprint = Blueprint('something', __name__, static_folder='static', url_prefix='/something')`

and in the template we refer to our static folder as it follows:

`{{url_for('something.static', filename=...)}}`

It seems kinda weird to me, that url_prefix is necessary for it to work, but whatever.